# python regex search findall capturing groups

Tags: python, regex

I just want to get "66664324", the content between ")" and "-".
Why did the `search` method get the ")" and "-" themselves.

```
a="(021)66664324-01"
b1=re.findall('\)(.*)-',a)
>['66664324']

b2=re.search('\)(.*)-',a).group()
>')66664324-'
```

What are differences between the two Code snippets.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try printing the group(1) in `re.search` instead of group(). Where `group()` prints the whole match but group(1) prints only the captured group 1(*printig chars which was present inside the group index 1*).

```
>>> a="(021)66664324-01"
>>> import re
>>> b2=re.search('\)(.*)-',a).group(1)
>>> b2
'66664324'
>>> b2=re.search('\)(.*)-',a).group()
>>> b2
')66664324-'
```

But `re.findall` gives the first preference to groups rather than the match and also it returns the results in lists but `search` didn't. So that this `b1=re.findall('\)(.*)-',a)` gives you the desired output. If a group is present then `re.findall` method would print only the groups not the match. If no groups are present, then only it prints the match.

```
>>> b1=re.findall('\)(.*)-',a)
>>> b1
['66664324']
>>> b1=re.findall('\).*-',a)
>>> b1
[')66664324-']
```

Comment: `findall` return a list ! he must print `b[0]`

Comment: @Kasra i think he's talking about the capturing groups.

Comment: Thank you! I have thought `re.findall` doesn't exist `captured groups`.I'm wrong.

Comment: for example:b1=re.findall(r'^\((.*)\)(.*)-(.*)$',a),it will return:
[('021', '66664324', '01')]

Comment: you need to escape `\(`, `\)`. try `re.findall(r'^\((.*)\)(.*)-(.*)$', a)`, it should return this `[('021', '66664324', '01')]`

Answer (score 0):

The difference is in b2.group(), which equals to b2.group(0).
And based on the python regex manual

> the search() method of patterns scans through the string, so the match
> may not start at zero in that case

So in your case the result starts at index of 1.
I had have tried your code with a little modification of the search rule and the expected result is at index 1.

> >>> a="(021)66664324-01"
>
> >>> re.search('\)([0-9]*)',a).group(1)
>
> '66664324'