# python: extracting (regex) pattern in a file without going through line by line (multiline search)

Tags: python, regex

I can extract a particualr pattern by reading mystring.txt file line by line and checking the line against re.search(r'pattern',line_txt) method.

Following is the mystring.txt

`

```
Client: //home/SCM/dev/applications/build_system/test_suite_linux/unit_testing



Stream: //MainStream/testing_branch

Options:    dir, norm accel, ddl



SubmitOptions:  vis, dir, cas, cat
```

`

using python, I can get the stream name as //MainStream/testing_branch

```
import re 
with open("mystring.txt",'r') as f:
    mystring= f.readlines()
    for line in mystring:
        if re.search(r'^Stream\:',line):

            stream_name = line.split('\t')[1]
            print stream_name
```

instead of going line by line in a loop, how is it possible to extract the same information by only using the re module?

Comment: Use f.read() for the whole buffer.  Then try a re.search()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use: `re.MULTILINE` with `re.search(..)`.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search(r'^Stream\:\s([^\n]+)', f.read(), re.MULTILINE).group(1)
'//MainStream/testing_branch'
```

Comment: This is what i was looking for. Could you please explain what does ([^\n]+) do? Thanks

Comment: ^ implies start where as $ implies end of string. ([^\n]) means starting with newline character.

Comment: `[^\n]+` means grab each character after `Stream:<whitespace>` that is not a newline. In other words, all character up to the newline character

Comment: fyi. Remove the `.group(1)` at the end of the `re.search()` call to return a "was there a match" boolean. Also: more depth on `re.search()` vs `re.findall()` here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25565090/605356

Answer (score 4):

You can read the file in one go and use `re.findall`(beware if the file is too large, loading it to main memory will not be good idea)

```
import re
content = open("input_file").read()
print(re.findall("^Stream: (.*)", content, re.M))
```

Comment: fyi. More depth on `re.search()` vs `re.findall()` here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37330608/605356

Answer (score 0):

## Here is the solution

```
f = open("mystring.txt").read()

import re

got = re.findall("Stream: .+\n", f)

got = got[0].strip()

print(got.split(": ")[1])
```